# Pandas extend index date using group by

Tags: python, pandas, date, indexing

I have a series of transactions similar to this table:

```
ID  Customer    Date    Amount
1   A        6/12/2018  33,223.00
2   A        9/20/2018  635.00
3   B        8/3/2018   8,643.00
4   B        8/30/2018  1,231.00
5   C        5/29/2018  7,522.00
```

However I need to get the mean amount of the last six months (as of today)

I was using

```
df.groupby('Customer').resample('W')['Amount'].sum()
```

And get something like this:

```
CustomerCode  PayDate   
A             2018-05-21                    268
              2018-05-28                   0.00
              2018-06-11                   0.00
              2018-06-18                472,657
              2018-06-25                   0.00
```

However with this solution I only get the range of dates where the customers had amount. I need to extend the weeks for each customer so I can get the whole range of the six months (in weeks). In this example I would need to get for customer A from the week of '2018-04-05' (which is exactly six months ago from today) till the week of today (filled with 0 of course since there was no amount)

Comment: I don't really understand where any of the numbers in your output are coming from

Comment: @user3483203 sorry but due to privacy concerns I had manually write them so they might not make much sense. But in any case I can create dummy data and provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Heres is the solution I found to my question. First I creates the dates I wanted (last six months but in frequency of weeks)

```
dates = pd.date_range(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12),
                      pd.datetime.today(),
                      freq='W')
```

Then I create a multi-index using the product of the customer with the dates.

```
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.Index(df['Customer'].unique()), 
                                          dates], 
                                         names=('Customer', 'Date'))
```

Then I reindex the df using the new created multi-index and lastly, I fill with zeroes the missing values.

```
df.reindex(multi_index)
df.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Resample is super flexible. To get a 6-month sum instead of the weekly sum you currently have all you need is:

```
df.groupby('Customer').resample('6M')['Amount'].sum()
```

That groups by month end; month start would be `'6MS'`.

More documentation on available frequencies can be found here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases